# C# UITypeEditor with Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid, uitypeeditor

I have created a custom `UITypeEditor` which launches a form (StringSelector) to display a list of strings which the user choses from. The problem is that this form needs to know what StringManager to use (stringmanage is simply a class which contains all the strings allowed in a List).

When I created this form I was passing in the StringManager as a parameter in the Constructor, but I cannot work out how i can do this with the UITypeEditor.

Below is my current code which uses a constructor which has no parameters, just to get the form to show, however there are obviously no strings as I didn't call the parameter version of the constructor.

How can I pass a parameter to the UITypeEditor which I can then use within the EditValue function? Many thanks.

```cs
class StringSelectorEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        IWindowsFormsEditorService svc = provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)) as IWindowsFormsEditorService;

        StringItem item = value as StringItem;

        if (svc != null)
        {
            // ###### How do I pass a reference to this EditValue function so that I can....
            using (StringSelector form = new StringSelector(/* ... INSERT IT HERE */))
            {
                form.Value = item;
                if (svc.ShowDialog(form) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    item = form.Value; // update object
                }
            }
        }
        return value; // can also replace the wrapper object here
    }
}
```

**UPDATED with additional detail:**
As requested, I have a class called ControlInstance which itself contains the populated StringManager. It is this ControlInstance Class which is passed to the PropertyGrid control and its accessor functions displayed in it including the above described StringSelectorEditor UITypeEditor reference. Here is a snippet of the code:

```cs
public class ControlInstance_Label : ControlInstance
{
    StringManager stringManager;
    string thisName = "";
    StringItem linkedStringItem;

    public ControlInstance_Label(String TextFilePath) 
    {
        // Code here which populates the StringManager with text from the above file
    }

    [Category("Design"), Description("Control Name")]
        public String Name
        {
            get { return thisName; }
            set { thisName = value; }
        }

    // THIS IS WERE I SOMEHOW NEED TO PASS IN THE StringManager Ref to the EditValue function of the custom UITypeEditor
    [Category("Design"), Description("Static String Linked to this Control")]
        [Editor(typeof(StringSelectorEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        public StringItem LinkedString
        {
            get { return linkedStringItem; }
            set { linkedStringItem = value; }
        }
}
```

Comment: Where is you StringManager instance stored/declared?

Comment: Outside of this StringSelectorEditor class, but can be accessed from the Class which uses this UITypeEditor.

Comment: Please be more accurate. Show some sample code for example.

Comment: Pretty unclear how *value* could possibly be a StringItem.  You'd put the [Editor] attribute on a property that stores the collection of StringItems.  Like the StringManager.  Just guessing without being able to see the attribute, the way it should be done.

Comment: I have added a bit more code above to my original post which I hope helps clear it up. So in fact as Hans as pointed out StringManager actually stores a list of StringItems (more then just a standard string).

Comment: StringManager contains `public List<StringItem> StringsList = new List<StringItem>(); // List of strings`

Comment: Doing a bit more research its starting to look like I cannot do what I thought without jumping through 100 hoops. Therefore, unless anyone can tell me otherwise I think I will just have to create my own custom Property Grid style control for my purpose.

Comment: So I ended up writing my own version of a property grid (specificially for my application) and its now working perfectly.. wish I had known this a few days ago... could have saved myself loads of time lol. Live and Learn. Thanks.

Comment: I know this is an old question and you ended up writing your own property grid. I wish I had seen this question sooner to post this answer! You don't need to implement a custom property grid, you can simply have access to the owner object of the property using `context` property of the `EditValue` method this way: `context.Instance`. Anyway, I posted the answer to help future readers. You also may find it useful for future projects :)

Answer (score 2):

`EditValue` method has a `context` parameter which is of type [`ITypeDescriptorContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedescriptorcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) and has an [`Instance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedescriptorcontext.instance(v=vs.110).aspx) property which is the owner object of the property that you are editing.

So you can have access to any public properties in your class by simply casting `context.Instance` to the owner class type. Also you can use reflection to have access to private members as well.

**Example**

Here is a class that accepts a `List<string>` in its constructor and I'm going to use those values when editing `SomeValue` property. To do so, I store the passed list in an invisible property `SomeList` and will use it in `EditValue` of my custom UI type editor. You can keep the list in a private property if you like and then extract values using reflection. Here is a simple `MyClass` implementation:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public List<String> SomeList { get; set; }
    public MyClass(List<String> list)
    {
        SomeList = list;
    }

    [Editor(typeof(MyUITypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Here in `MyUITypeEditor` in `EditValue` method, I extract list values from `context.Instance` which is the instance of the object which we are editing its property. Then just for example I show extracted values in a message box:

```
public class MyUITypeEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
        IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        //Just as an example, show a message box containing values from owner object
        var list = ((MyClass)context.Instance).SomeList;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You can choose from {0}.",
            string.Join(",", list)));

        return base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
    }
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }
}
```

To test it, it's enough to show an instance of `MyClass` in a property grid and try to edit `SomeValue` property in property grid:

```
var myObject = new MyClass(new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" });
this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = myObject;
```